# How to integrate this modified Bessel function of second kind

Tags: definite-integrals, bessel-functions

I am getting stuck in integrating the below equation that includes modified Bessel function of second kind:

$$\int_0^{\frac{y}{\eta}}K_0\left(\frac{|x|}{\sqrt{\sigma_a^2\sigma_b^2}}\right)\mathrm{d}x$$

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the appropriate change of variable and
$$\int K_0(t)\,dt=\frac{\pi}{2} \,  t \,(\pmb{L}_{-1}(t) K_0(t)+\pmb{L}_0(t) K_1(t))$$ where appear  the modified Struve functions.

Learn about them since they appear in most integrals of Bessel functions.